# v-treeview - Closing and Opening only the level 1 nodes

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, treeview, vuetify.js

I made a button for my tree view that will open and close all the nodes.

The button:

```
<v-btn @click="toggleTreeview" />
```

My v-tree:

```
<v-treeview 
  :value="x"
  @input="y"
  :items="[tree]"
  :open-all="expanded" 
  ref="myTreeview"
></v-treeview>
```

The method:

```
toggleTreeview() {
  this.expanded = !this.expanded;
  this.$refs.myTreeview.updateAll(this.expanded);
},
```

What I would like to do, is that the button will CLOSE and OPEN only the Level 1 nodes.

- Level 0

  - Level 1

    - Level 2
    - Level 2
  - Leve 1

Would that be possible using the v-treeview API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `open` prop lets you control which exact nodes should be expanded at any given time.  It's not clear from your question how the entire tree should react for all cases. For example, should Level 1 nodes expand if the parent Level 0 node is collapsed, or should Level 0 node expand as well?  What about in the reverse when toggling "off"?

I suppose I'll leave those details for you to decide, but just to show how the `open` prop can work, here is a [codepen](https://codepen.io/yoduh/pen/ZEmqaoe) and the relevant code below:

```html
<v-btn @click="toggleLevel1">Toggle Level 1 Nodes</v-btn>
<v-treeview
  open-all
  :open.sync="level1"
  :items="items"
  item-key="id"
></v-treeview>
```

```js
  data: () => ({
    level1: [],
    toggle: false,
    items: [...]
  }),
  methods: {
    toggleLevel1() {
      if (this.toggle)
        // nodes that should be open when toggling "on"
        this.level1 = [1, 5, 6, 10, 15, 19, 20]
      else
        // nodes that should be open when toggling "off"
        this.level1 = [1, 5, 15, 19]
      
      this.toggle = !this.toggle
    }
  }
```